# Freemarker: assign interpreted variable to other variable

Tags: freemarker, assign

I would like to assign the result of an interpreted variable to another varialbe.

Freemarker provides the built-in `?interpret` to interpret a variable holding an ftl expression. See http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_interpret

If I do

```
[#if var1?has_content && var1?starts_with(r"${")]
    [#assign interpretedValue = var1?interpret!""]
    [@interpretedValue/]
[/#if]
```

The `[@interpretedValue/]` will output the interpreted value.

However, I'd like to assign the value of the interpreted value to a variable (in order to do some things such as `?has_content` in the rest of my code). I tried `[#assign varInterpretedValue = @interpretedValue]` but this does not work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
[#assign capturedOutput][@(var1!'')?interpret /][/#assign]
${capturedOutput} [#-- Attention! Put this into #noescape if you are inside #escape! --]
```

Note that the `!''` suff has to before the `?interpret`, otherwise it doesn't do anything (since the result of `?interpret` is always non-null).

Comment: Your solution was almost right & put me on the right path (see solution in my answer). When trying this solution, I get the following error: var1!''?interpret is not a user-defined directive. It is a freemarker.template.SimpleScalar

Comment: Right... that should be `(var1!'')?interpret`. I have updated my answer.